# How to get count of Markers within circle radius in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a Google map where I populate with multiple markers, I then add a addListener for right click event.

On a right click, I add a temp marker with a circle radius of 50000 meters,upon dropping this marker, I would like to get the count of markers that fall within the radius.

Comment: Yes, show some code please. It is impossible to guess what you really mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I should have posted some code up front, but managed to resolve it on my own. as per below.

```
var loc1 = location; //Marker Radius Co-ords
var loc2 = new google.maps.LatLng(latSplit, lonSplit); //Marker Co-ords

var diff = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(loc1, loc2));


 if (diff < circle.getRadius()) {
           alert(loc2 + " Inside Radius");
   } else {
            alert(loc2 + " Outside Radius");
   }
```